# Examples with the purpose of learning LaTeX?

Tags: learning, tutorials

I have a basic understanding of LaTeX. But I would like to learn more through LaTeX examples or real world usage (probably commented). Where can such be found?

Comment: @xport: I think the {latex-general} tag *is* appropriate here.

Comment: @lockstep: according to some moderators (I don't want to say the names), `latex-general` should not be used.

Comment: @xport: it's the {latex} tag that you're not supposed to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sources of a lot of the examples from the LaTeX books can be found here: [Examples from CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/examples/)

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing what "real world" you inhabit.  If you're looking for math examples, then the `mathmode` documentation is essential. (It should be part of your TeX distribution.)  The *LaTeX Companion 3rd Edition* by F. Mittelbach, M. Goosens, J. Braams, D. Carlisle and C. Rowley (Addison Wesley) is full of example code with extremely good explanations.  For examples of drwawing with `pgf/tikz`, see the [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).  Maybe others can add more suggestions to this list.

Comment: all the examples are avilable as stand alone documents on CTAN. See my answer

Answer (score 6):

The best way to learn LaTeX is by using it. The "real world" you are presumably interested in is the world of things you actually want LaTeX to do for you. And if you want to learn about those things, try them!

The already mentioned link includes several excellent resources (the LaTeX wikibook, the not so short introduction...) but be selective! There is a lot to learn, so don't just sit down to read a LaTeX book cover-to-cover. Not at first. Try to do something (typeset an article, draw a picture in TikZ, write a letter...) in LaTeX and when you get stuck, search out the relevant parts of the above mentioned resources.

I think the sort of thing you are requesting (commented source code examples?) will be of limited use, unless you want to do more or less exactly the same thing as what that code does. You're much better off trying to write your own code and learning that way.

Edit: [Another useful list of resources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4420/215) (There's a lot of overlap with the other link...)

Comment: Well, the reason why I asked this question was actually to be able to use LaTeX in the real world. By finding examples that contains things similar to what I would like to do, and then study how they do it.

Comment: @paldepind what is the real world? Is the suggestion that academics writing papers in LaTeX doesn't count as "the real world" and that therefore their examples wouldn't be helpful? Do you mean the world of professional publishing? What sort of documents get produced in the "real world"?