# Comprehensive book on Kile

Tags: editors, books, kile

Finally, I have decided to migrate from Office to LaTeX. That is why I have chosen Kile as an editor, for many known reasons that I don't want to list here because of space.

That's why I need a comprehensive book or would be even better to find some video training course on Kile. The reason for that is that I have never worked with Kile before.

Could you help me to choose a good starting point on learning Kile?

Comment: It seems to me like Kile's online documentation (http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/index.html) is quite comprehensive.  If that is not sufficient, for what else do you desire in a manual?

Comment: This seems off-topic. Kile is just an editor so there isn't much to “learn” about it. Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) for some suggestions about learning LaTeX itself. If you do have any specific question about doing some particular LaTeX task in Kile do feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @juan I disagree. Kile is just an editor, but it's an editor designed for writing LaTeX. It has a particular take on how to do tag completion, how to mark up code and so on. I think Kile is enough of a "friend" of TeX that this isn't off topic. That said, I don't think there are good answers apart from "RTFM". But that's a different issue.

Comment: completely agree with Seamus. Thanks for support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word and LaTeX work quite differently. A lot of what has been said in answers to other questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4420/215) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/215)) applies to working with Kile. Kile is just an editor. A lot of learning LaTeX is editor-independent.

As has been already mentioned the [Kile documentation](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/index.html) will also be helpful. Kile is built on Kate, so the [Kate documentation](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdesdk/kate/index.html) might be helpful for lower level issues.

Answer (score 1):

http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/M.Baltovic/kile/

For more information search with Google.