# List of books written in LaTeX with the source available

Tags: sourcecode, books, big-list

Is there a list of open source LaTeX books? I've only found [these books](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324110351/http://opensourcemath.org/books/) (the link points to a web archive), but I want to know if there is a list with more diversity as this has only mathematical books. I want to find open source books about physics, chemistry, electronics...

My aim is to use these as a source of inspiration. 
For example if I wanted to do a digital circuit I would like to take a look at a book written with LaTeX about electronics just to see how other people do it. Here for example is a physics book with the source available http://www.lightandmatter.com/lm/ .  In this
book I've seen that putting images in the chapter entry looks nice.

Comment: Are you looking for books about LaTeX or written in LaTeX?

Comment: i'm not entirely clear about what you're looking for.  "open source" implies that you want access to the latex source files as well as to the output (and your tagging this with "sourcecode" implies the same), so just free books prepared using latex won't satisfy your requirement.  is this correct?  the options are not likely to be extensive.

Comment: This question is suited better for physics.SX

Comment: Given the backround, that you were very interested in MediaWiki stuff and its LaTeX-export, are you looking for sourcecode examples by a *non-machine* to see how others are writing (La)TeX code?

Comment: yeah for example if I wanted to do a digital circuit I would like to take a look at a book wrote with latex about electronics just to see how other people do it. Here for example is a physics book with the source available http://www.lightandmatter.com/lm/

Comment: Arturo, that is not the way to go. Other people make mistakes, some of them a lot. After reading an up to date introduction, you will be able to google your problem, assess the solutions given, and decide to go with the package documentation for all further reference. It might take a bit of time in the beginning, but will save you so much more time in the future trying to debug strange code by a stranger.

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic? It's about books written using LaTeX for which the authors have made the source public. I think it's not off-topic. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: I don't want to use the books to learn latex. It's a source of inspiration. For example in the lightandmatter book I've seen that putting images in the chapter entry looks nice.

Comment: may be related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Comment: By the way, the author of Light and Matter is a member here as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6853/ben-crowell

Comment: I have a number, depending on how you count, but they are math.  See http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra and http://joshua.smcvt.edu/proofs.  The source is in a public repo.

Comment: @Arturo: Please don't edit answers. You may suggests edits in a comment to an answer, but I don't like my answers to be edited unless there are severe errors or typos. I did not mention Jim Hefferon's as it is his 'job' to provide an answer.

Comment: I've added [tag:big-list] and I will suggest again that this could be a very useful list to have on-site. I also suggest again that this question be made community wiki, as is common with our other [tag:big-list] questions.

Comment: How do I put it as community wiki?

Comment: @Arturo I don't know how you can once the question has been posted (they changed this up a little relatively recently), but a mod in our chatroom might be able to help.  Or really, any chatroom / meta site -- the platform is the same across the network.

Comment: You can get a lot of results by simply searching Google with the `site:` option enabled, specifying GitHub: https://www.google.com/#q=LaTeX+source+site:github.com -- Most of these results show LaTeX source for various projects -- books, resumes, theses, etc.

Answer (score 28):

---

**Books about (La)TeX**

---

***Tout ce que vous avez toujours voulu savoir sur LaTeX sans jamais oser le demander***

Vincent Lozano's [Tout… sur LaTeX](http://framabook.org/tout-sur-latex/) is licenced under the licence [art libre](http://artlibre.org/), typeset using LaTeX. An introduction book in French, clear and whose reading is rather easy.

- [pdf for screen](http://framabook.org/docs/latex/framabook-versionenligne_v1_5.pdf)
- [pdf to print](http://framabook.org/docs/latex/framabook-versionpapier-nb-prepress_v1_5.pdf)
- [sources with figures](http://framabook.org/docs/latex/ToutLaTeX_1_5_2013-11-22_framabook-avec-figs.tar.bz2)
- [sources witout figures](http://framabook.org/docs/latex/ToutLaTeX_1_5_2013-11-22_framabook-sans-fig.tar.bz2)
- [buy a hardcopy](http://www.enventelibre.org/livres/37-tout-sur-latex.html)

http://framabook.org/tout-sur-latex/

***TeX by Topic***

[Viktor Eijkhout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38308/victor-eijkhout)'s [*TeX by Topic*](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html) is licensed under the [GNU Free Documentation License (FDL)](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html). It is typeset using LaTeX, and the source is available at GitHub [here](https://github.com/VictorEijkhout/tex-by-topic).

***The TeXbook***

The question asks specifically about LaTeX, but the one and only *The TeXbook* by D.E. Knuth himself is a fine example of a complete book typeset with TeX. Its source is available on CTAN as the package [`texbook`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook). Please note that this source is available for inspection/learning only and is not to be compiled.

***LaTeX for Complete Novices* as well as all other titles in [The Dickimaw LaTeX Series](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/index.html)**

This collection of books written by [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) is licensed under the GNU FDL just like *TeX by Topic*. The sources for each book<sup>1</sup> along with the typeset books in an array of output formats are available at the respective home pages:

- [*LaTeX for Complete Novices*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)
- [*Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/)
- [*LaTeX for Administrative Work*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/)
- [*Creating a PDF Document using PDFLaTeX*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/pdfdoc/)
- [*Converting LaTeX `.sty` Style Files to LaTeX2HTML `.perl` Style Files*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/l2h/)
- [*Creating Technical Posters with LaTeX*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/posters/)
- [*Creating a LaTeX minimal example*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/)

---

<sup>1</sup> A caveat potentially relevant to this question is noted near the download link for each book's source code:

> Note that the source code is very complicated as it required creating four different versions of the document: the HTML version, the A4 PDF version, the screen PDF version and the 7x10 inch paperback version. It should not be considered an example file for beginners.

Comment: To the downvoter: it'd be nice if you commented with your reasoning so I know how I might improve this post.

Comment: "I like my answer more", perhaps :/

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614197/source-code-of-books-made-with-tex-latex-to-learn/29577165#29577165

Comment: @MattAllegro updated with the whole Dickimaw LaTeX Series, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 20):

---

**Physics**

---

[Simple Nature](http://www.lightandmatter.com/area1sn.html) by [Ben Crowell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6853/ben-crowell)

[image]

- [HTML](http://www.lightandmatter.com/html_books/0sn)
- [PDF](http://www.lightandmatter.com/simple.pdf)
- LaTeX Source git clone git://lightandmatter.com/physics

[Mechanics](http://www.lightandmatter.com/mechanics/) by [Ben Crowell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6853/ben-crowell)

[image]

- [HTML](http://www.lightandmatter.com/mechanics/)
- [PDF](http://www.lightandmatter.com/me.pdf)
- LaTeX source git clone git://lightandmatter.com/physics

[Light and Matter](http://www.lightandmatter.com/lm/) by [Ben Crowell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6853/ben-crowell)

[image]

- [HTML](http://www.lightandmatter.com/html_books/lm/)
- [PDF](http://www.lightandmatter.com/lm.pdf)
- LaTeX source git clone git://lightandmatter.com/physics

[Special Relativity](http://www.lightandmatter.com/sr/) by [Ben Crowell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6853/ben-crowell)

- [PDF](http://www.lightandmatter.com/sr/sr.pdf)
- LaTeX source git clone https://github.com/bcrowell/special_relativity.git

[General Relativity](http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel) by [Ben Crowell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6853/ben-crowell)

- [PDF](http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel/genrel.pdf)
- [HTML](http://www.lightandmatter.com/html_books/genrel)
- [LaTeX source](http://github.com/bcrowell/general_relativity/tree/master)

[image]

Comment: Adding parts of a solution from an answer from other users (or editing their answer -- you know exactly, what I mean, and users with more than 10k can see the answer deleted by me!) and then use a self-accept is far more than doubtful.

Comment: Arturo, this *really* isn't kosher if it's not a CW post to begin with.

Comment: the posted link to "LaTeX sources" of the Cryptotoday book does not contain any .tex files, only PDF, PS, HTML and TXT. So it's not a good example IMHO.

Answer (score 11):

---

**Computer Science**

---

### Complexité Algorighmique by [Sylvain Perifel](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~sperifel/)

- [html](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~sperifel/livre_complexite.html)
- [sources](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~sperifel/latex.html)
- [pdf](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~sperifel/complexite.pdf)

Uses XeLaTeX

### The [Chicago Journal of Theoretical Computer Science](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/)

This journal publishes the sources of *all* its articles.
For instance,

*Computational Models with No Linear
Speedup*

- [html](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/2012/7/contents.html)
- [pdf](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/2012/7/cj12-07.pdf)
- [sources (zip)](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/2012/7/cj12-07.zip).

### Homotopy Type Theory: Univalent Foundations of Mathematics by [The Univalent Foundations Program Institute for Advanced Study](http://homotopytypetheory.org)

- [html](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)
- [nightly builds](https://github.com/HoTT/book/wiki/Nightly-Builds) (different pdf version available: for screens, readers, to print, etc.)
- [sources](https://github.com/HoTT/book/) (start with [`main.tex`](https://github.com/HoTT/book/blob/master/main.tex))

Answer (score 10):

Although `Light and matter` has been mentioned already, Ben Crowell has also a nice book on General Relativity, available from here (as well as the sources)

http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel

as

- PDF
- HTML
- LaTeX source (github account)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematics

---

### Algebra

---

[Linear Algebra](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/) by [Jim Hefferon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/339/jim-hefferon)

- [PDF](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf)
- LaTeX source hg clone https://code.google.com/p/linear-algebra/

Matrix Arithmetic by Harold W. Ellingsen

- [PDF](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/MatrixArithmetic.PDF)
- [LaTeX source](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/MatrixArithmetic.tex)

Algebra - First year (in french) by [Exo7](http://exo7.emath.fr/)

[image]

- [PDF](https://github.com/exo7math/exo7-livre/raw/master/livre-algebre-1.pdf)
- [LaTeX sources](https://github.com/exo7math/exo7-livre) on GitHub.

---

### Analysis

---

Analysis - First year (in french) by [Exo7](http://exo7.emath.fr/)

[image]

- [PDF](https://github.com/exo7math/exo7-livre/raw/master/livre-analyse-1.pdf)
- [LaTeX sources](https://github.com/exo7math/exo7-livre) on GitHub.

---

### Everything

---

Le Frido - Les quelques premières années de mathématiques by [Laurent Claessens](http://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/).

[image]

- [PDF](http://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/lefrido.pdf)
- [LaTeX sources](https://github.com/LaurentClaessens/mazhe) on GitHub.

Comment: Matrix Arithmetic source file connot be compiled, one should have a look at [https://code.google.com/p/linear-algebra/source/browse/](https://code.google.com/p/linear-algebra/source/browse/).

Answer (score 1):

Stitz Zeager Open Source Mathematics:

http://www.stitz-zeager.com

Answer (score 0):

Martin Thoma uses some very straightforward LaTeX in typesetting [Pride and Prejudice](https://github.com/MartinThoma/free-books/tree/master/Austen/Pride%20and%20Prejudice) and some [Sherlock Holmes](https://github.com/MartinThoma/free-books/tree/master/Doyle/Sherlock%20Holmes) stories.

I wrote up my lecture notes on beginning abstract algebra: [Concrete Algebra](https://github.com/Ben-McKay/concrete-algebra).

The [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/) has TeX source for most of its papers and books, including hundreds of books: [Modern Antennas and Microwave Circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.08484)

Answer (score 0):

In a rather different subject there is the user manual for the `memoir` document class.

The source is available at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/doc-src/memman.tex

There are other files in that `doc-src` directory that will be of assistance if you want to process `memman.tex`.

I'm assuming that you have the `memoir` class on your computer so `texdoc memoir` or `texdoc memman` will show the typeset manual.

Answer (score 0):

The [Open Logic Project](https://openlogicproject.org) has several open source, open access textbooks, like:

[image]

https://github.com/OpenLogicProject/set-theory

[image]

https://github.com/rzach/forallx-yyc

[image]

https://github.com/rzach/incompleteness-computability