# Database for many TeX documents

Tags: resources

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Otherwise I would be happy to be guided to change the place of it.

For some task of data mining I need to have access to a large set of tex documents, which preferably are relevant to technical topics such as math, physics, computer science, etc.

Is there any open-source website offering this kind of documents in large numbers?

Comment: ArXiv is the obvious one ... (though this seems off-topic to me)

Comment: I posted it in UX and they guided me here. I am not sure where I can post it. Thank you though. I didn't know arXiv provides the tex file as well.

Comment: I really like [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230526/34551) about book's source, on this website. Are you looking for quantity, for quality ? You could, for instance, just browse [all the `tex` files hosted at github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3ATeX&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=TeX&l=) or [ask google for `tex` files](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3D*.tex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=filetype:tex). I'm afraid there is no simple way to download massive tex files from arxiv. You could try http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/ as well.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. No quality is not important, but I need articles with plenty of math expressions.... beside google is not a very good solution as the limit size on the number of articles is pretty small...

Comment: TeX distributions contain many documents (manuals, text books, examples etc.) and many of then are in `.tex` format, though some are `.dtx` etc.