# where I can get the complete source code of a typical book for learning

Tags: books, learning

I'm new to the TeX community. I want to know where I can get the complete source code of a typical book for learning.

Comment: Is the following what you're after?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230526/list-of-books-written-in-latex-with-the-source-available