# Single Line Break in Latex to Single Line Break in Text?

Tags: line-breaking, parskip

This definitely seems like an answered question somewhere, but how can I make a single line break in the latex source code correspond to a line break in the text?

For example, I'd like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

as opposed to

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Sentence 1

Sentence 2
\end{document}
```

with the extra line break.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I haven't tried it with LaTeX, but the command `\obeylines` is a TeX primitive intended for this purpose.

Comment: @barbara Can I adjust that to work for math-environment-type code that uses linebreaks, like writing matrices?

Comment: @KevinMoy What's the problem with typing ``\\`` at the end of matrix rows?

Comment: @KevinMoy -- It seems you may not be very familiar with LaTeX, in particular the difference in treatment between text and math, and especially the concept of display vs. in-text math.  It might be helpful to refer to some basic documentation; here are two questions with copious information: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/), [List of books written in LaTeX with the source available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230526).

Comment: @KevinMoy -- `\obeylines` is intended specifically for use with text.  It is particularly useful for formatting poetry and verbatim blocks.  If you want help with math, your question should say so.

Comment: @egreg that worked fine, thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that second comment was all I really was asking for. Thanks for your help.