# Clickable, bottom page reference ?! Possible ?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, footnotes, citing, urls

I'm new here but I see the place looks hyperactive. I guess I'll ask a lot in the next months.
So new to LaTeX and starting my PhD thesis redaction.

I got this template for a PhD thesis at openwetware here http://openwetware.org/wiki/LaTeX_template_for_PhD_thesis. Very nice. An interactive pdf is generated with clickable reference between figures and parts/sections and also references. Plus the reference implemented with the correct URL are clickable. I went inside the .bst file  but it is very barbarian to me. :s

So I 'm very happy with it but there is one big problem. I need references of my bibliography at the very bottom (like footnotes) of the page I first cite them. And. I'd like to conserve this interactive property of the references. Is that possible ?

I'd be infinitely grateful for any help.

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't use such templates. It is easier for you to build you own header. Your template has also some mistakes.  You can start with a modern documentclass like `scrbook` or `memoir`

Comment: I know so little about latex .. makes me scared to make a whole file ... What errors / mistake did you see ?

Comment: oo1on: Don't be scared, and read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/best-way-to-start-using-latex-tex) question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template you pointed to uses the [natbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package to manage citations and the bibliography. While this package features a lot of possible citation styles, to the best of my knowledge it isn't suited for footnote citations containing (as I assume you want) the full bibliographic information. That's another reason why, as Marco pointed out, you should start with classes like `scrbook` or `memoir` and add packages and personal modifications only as needed.

In the following compilable example, I use the `scrbook` class (part of [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) plus the [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) packages to produce clickable citations that point to the full bibliographic information in the footnote.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/best-way-to-start-using-latex-tex},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: Thank you Marco & lockstep for those quickreplies. Will look at it tomorrow ... getting late here :/ lockstep I compiled your file. Will it be possible to refer and link a citation (being as footnote) to an external url ? Thanks again for the replies !

Comment: @oo1on: External URL added to the example.