# biblatex: is it possible to combine two styles?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

Ok so after my first question yesterday [Clickable, bottom page reference ?! Possible ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20571/6102) and based on the received answer I decided to head for `biblatex`, install biber and all. But the documentation is tough : I found the german tutorial but except Dancke shön I don't know what to say/do.

Ok so my question is simple.

I loaded `biblatex` this way

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,sorting=none,hyperref]{biblatex}
```

And the American Chemical Society style is perfect (well almost what I'm looking for).

Now this option loading verbose

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1,sorting=none,hyperref]{biblatex}
```

allows me to have footnote citations as I wished!

But I would like to have footnote citations with op cit ibid. etc ... and the ACS format (or whateever else format.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is quite easy.
`biblatex` allows you to choose a style for the bibliography, and a style for the citation. 
It is clearly written in the `biblatex` documentation.

```
bibstyle=chem-acs,citestyle=verbose-trad1
```

Instead of your `style=chem-acs`

Answer (score 6):

As Martigan said, in principle it is possible to combine different styles for citations and bibliographies. I'll add two caveats:

- With the standard styles shipped with `biblatex`, certain combinations (especially with a non-default sorting scheme on top) may hamper the accessibility of bibliography entries. An example would be `citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=none` (the last option will sort the entries according to their in-text citation order).
- Custom styles available on CTAN may be programmed in a way that the citation and bibliography style files are mutually dependend, and combining any of them with a different style may result in non-functional output or even outright error messages. An example are the styles included in the [biblatex-dw](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw) package (an author-title style and a verbose style that offer features over and above that of the corresponding standard styles).

Comment: Ok lockstep. So a cleaner way would be to simply get to modify the style to obtain author,journal,year,vol (without title) and with the the verbose cite style ? Is that it ? But how do I modify these options ? (for example get rid of the title ? Is editing a style sheet the only way ? (i'm starting to think that natbib was easier more documentation at least...for me ..)  By the way if I would like a citation to be cited only the first time it appears in the footnot and then no op cit or ibid wath cite style should I use ?

Comment: @oo1on: I would skim the documentation of custom styles and look for "Don't mix those style with other ones" warnings. If not, I would at least look for "funny" output when combining styles. Regarding your "What style should I use" question: Obviously you want full bibliographic data the first time an entry is cited, but what exactly (!) should the output look like the second time?

Comment: @lockstep Ok so to be clear here would be brievly described my dream : citation as exponent numbers (no () no [] no Author,date. Then the first time a ref is cited it appears as footnote with the exponent number corresponding to the one it will be attributed in the bibliography at the end. If cited a second time nothing happends only the same citation number but no footnote at all ! I'm almost going crazy not being able to do this : it's so current in al the Word redacted thesis in my lab, I don't get it why I can't do this easily with latex.

Comment: @lockstep and the citation style would be idealy Name Firstname (only initial), Journal, Year (in bold), vol, pages.

Comment: oo1on: I see ... but you should definitely post your request as a new question.

Comment: @lockstep Ok I will.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

after loading biblatex or set the `natbib` compatibility layer (which uses this command to include the comma). I found that works better as I had some side effects using apa as style compared to `authoryear`.

(from http://meinews.niuz.biz/biblatex-t500020.html#td_post_4652515)

Comment: Hi Jasc, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) By indenting your code with four spaces, or wrapping it in backticks if you want it inline, code is displayed nicely. I've done this for you. Click on edit to see the difference.