# Getting \parencite to print out (<author>, <year>) when using `biblatex-apa`

Tags: biblatex

I'm using BibLaTeX-apa to cite references, but I'm having trouble getting a citation to print out (, ) when I reference to it in the main text. I'm using the `\parencite` command as is advised on the first page of the [biblatex-apa-test documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf) and what I get is ( ), that is, without the comma.

I've been trying to write a minimal example but I haven't figured out how to create database within the document so the example I provide uses my own database.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{/library.bib}
\begin{document}
Test \parencite{Lamme2006}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Styles are applied in the order they are set. Looks like you want `apa` for both the bibliography and citation styles so just use `style=apa` instead of `bibstyle=apa,style=authoryear`.

For reference, you can use different styles in the same document. Some more information can be found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20605/4483).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Same problem though.

Comment: @Speldosa `style` sets both the citation and bibliography styles. Why not just use `style=apa` instead of `bibstyle=apa, style=authoryear`?

Comment: Actually I've always used style=apa to set both bibstyle and citestyle to apa. I'd always get the comma that way.

Comment: @LianTze The styles are applied in the order they are specified. So setting `style=authoryear` afterward undoes the edit you suggested.

Comment: @Audrey Why? Because I'm an idiot :) It worked. Thanks. Provide it as an answer an I'll accept it.

Comment: @LianTze Can you edit your post? I think it had the right idea, and I'd prefer not to add another answer. UPDATE: Nevermind. My changes were approved. Please feel free to edit it further.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks for the great edit! I missed all the excitement as it was night time this part of the world. :)