# How can I start using resume templates with LaTeX?

Tags: templates, resume

I am trying to write my resume using Latex, to have a better document and attract more interest from the recruiters. Internet is full of places with lots of templates and walk-troughs to build it up. But, I am having a nightmare with all the stuff about packages, extensions, modes etc.

For instance, if I use this [template](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/03/professional-cv-latex/#more-10) in the compilation time the system tells me that I need to have installed Xetex, in order to use a library. But I have it installed already! (at least Ubuntu Sw Centre told that).

I need a briefly introduction of how libraries works in Tex, and an explanation how to use the different versions of Tex (e.g. europass, cvtex, etc).

Could anyone help me?

Comment: *Installing* xetex is not enough, if you are compiling a document that uses xetex-specific libraries. You need to *use* xetex or xelatex (instead of latex).

Comment: I modified the vague title. The link to the template in the question is not working, please correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is a bit vague. However, I will show you some questions and answers helping you to start.

To learn how libraries/styles generally work in LaTeX, follow the suggestions in the answers to these questions:

- [Best Way to Start Using LaTeX/TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/best-way-to-start-using-latex-tex)
- [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

Regarding installation have a look at the respective package documentation or look here:

- [{installing} + {packages} tag search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing+packages)

Each packages usually provides a documentation of how to use it. However, here's a nice tutorial:

- [Writing a CV in LaTeX](http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/5)

Perhaps also have a look at

- [LaTeX templates for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Comment: Thanks for the links, mate. I had learned working with LaTeX a few years back, and am interested in taking it up seriously. Those links are very good places to start off with!