# How to get started to typeset mathematical proofs with LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, amsthm, learning

I want to start using LaTeX to organize my proofs into a readable fashion. This motif is due to my professors preferring e-mail communication instead of reading a chicken-scratch proof. I know enough LaTeX such that I can post on math.SE and make my question readable, but I do not know how to include LaTeX in a document.

How do I make my proof into a LaTeX document?

Comment: Just as you would with mathjax's but now you need to declare your packages and the document type.

Comment: Have a look at [Best Way to Start Using LaTeX/TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4420/15717)

Comment: Good resources for math: [mathmode by Her­bert Voß](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) and [Short Math Guide for LATEX by Michael Downes](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf). Full detailed [math-into-latex-4 by Ge­orge Grätzer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/Math_into_LaTeX-4/Short_Course.pdf). Remember to use AMS developed LaTeX classes specifically for math [`amsart` `amsbook` and `amsproc`](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex) which are part of major TeX distributions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The skeleton is as follows,

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{thm}
$ax^2+bx+c=0$ has 2 real roots if $D>0$.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
This is my proof that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has 2 real roots if $D>0$.
\[
x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{D}}{4ac}
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more detailed at a glance tutorial, visit [Theorem](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems).

Comment: Forgot to mention above. You have to switch the document class from `standalone` to `article` because the former is used just for creating the image above.

Comment: I know there is a typo in the quadratic formula. Ignore it!

Comment: Does `amsart` load `amsthm` package ? if not why (very strange though) ?