# TexPad without MacTex

Tags: installing, mactex, texpad

I'm just a beginner with LaTeX. According to its website, "Texpad iOS comes with our own implementation of LaTeX compiler."

It seems to me one may edit a .tex file on their Mac, and then typeset the code into a PDF on their iPad with the help of TexPad for iOS. So one may feasibly work with LaTeX without installing MacTex, I wonder?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 1):

**I have not tried it, so my observations will be skewed**, however on reading the 5* reviews the ios app for ipad seems to have limitations that after a while may result in using a lap/desktop solution. Possibly good for small simple documents but may lead to higher cost of ownership later.

Trying to be objective rather than subjective. 
In relation to your Questions

Both are editors that typeset

The ios version has a bundle manager to add "packages on the fly", and uses the cloud for some typesetting (so may not be endorsed by corporates). There are alternative editors that are cloud based but allow offline editing.

To compare online issues Vs offline **some** valid pointers are in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193810/online-latex-editor-or-local-latex-editor)

Some users may find it useful to be able to make "notes on the go" when they have downloaded the required "bundles" in which case it could be an valued asset, however if working on-line there are potential overhead costs (e.g. network charges / outages).

The main version at twice the price has much lower ratings and also requires additional TeX Distribution, so for mainstream use I would advise sticking with a more conventional solution.

Overall a trial version is probably a good taster for how an IDE can look good.
But do compare  how it behaves "under the hood" with a sample of the most complex document you think you will compile.