# Can I use my own classes and packages in ShareLaTex or Overleaf

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf

I would like to use my own classes and packages in all my projects and I wonder if it's possible to do that, working with Overleaf or ShareLatex.

Of course, I don't want to paste my personal .cls and .sty in each project.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: On Overleaf your custom .cls and .sty files still need to be in each project you want to use them with, either by uploading them to the project directly or by the "Add file from other project" function as a linked file. To make the process easier, you can first create a project that contains all your usual .cls and .sty files, and then use "Open a Copy" from your Overleaf dashboard to create clones from it. Each newly created project like this will then contains the custom .cls and .sty files.

Comment: It is a lot easier just to input a .tex file containing all your definitions in the preamble.

Comment: Lim : do you know if some change in an original .cls will be effective in the cloned .cls ?   John : this is not just that simple. I regularly create several types of documents (articles, books...) in differents sizes (a4, a5, a6) and different constraints, thus a single .tex is not the best choice.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B, added an answer with some links to help articles on OL.

Answer (score 10):

On Overleaf, your custom `.cls` and `.sty` files still need to be in each project you want to use them with, either by uploading them to the project directly or by the ["Add file from other project"](https://www.overleaf.com/help/226-can-i-share-files-e-dot-g-bib-and-some-graphics-across-my-projects) function as a linked file.

Alternatively, you can first create a project that contains all your usual `.cls` and `.sty` files, and then use ["Open a Copy"](https://www.overleaf.com/help/49-can-i-start-a-new-overleaf-project-from-an-existing-one) from your Overleaf dashboard to create clones from it. Each newly created project like this will then contain the custom `.cls` and `.sty` files.

Comment: Once everything is finished with the merge, can you post an answer to [Comparison: ShareLaTeX vs Overleaf (formerly WriteLaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179030/37907)?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, will remember to do that :-)

Comment: Question: where must the .cls and .sty files be located?  I put mine in a styles folder, but Overleaf does not see them.  Must everything go in the project root?  It would be nice if Overleaf allowed one project to be in the search path of another, so I could just make a new project for each of my class directories and tell a project that I want them in my search path.