# How to write a chemical equation for an reaction that is still fitting inside the document?

Tags: pdf, chemfig, mol2chemfig

I am writing a lab report for my Chemistry class, and I would like to write a chemical reaction for the following reaction that looks like this.

[image]

I have tried the following command to make this reaction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.6}{\ce{\chemfig{O=[:15]-[:69](-[:123,,,2]HO)=_[:357](-[:51,,,1]OH)-[:285](<[:213]O-[:141])-[:339](<[:39,,,1]OH)-[:279]-[:339,,,1]OH} + \chemfig{O=[:19]-[:73]-[:1]-[:289](=[:343]O)-[:217]N(-[:145])-[:271]Br} -> \chemfig{O=[:231]-[:285](-[:339](<[:39,,,1]OH)-[:279]-[:339,,,1]OH)<[:213]O-[:141](=[:195]O)-[:69](-[:357])=[:123]O} + \chemfig{O=[:18]-[:72]--[:288](=[:342]O)-[:216]\mcfbelow{N}{H}(-[:144])} + \chemfig{Br-Br}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, the result is not what I expected. The compounds are not properly lined up.

[image]

Can anyone be able to help me with this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Comment: Could you please make your cdoe compilable (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Comment: I will work on that. Please wait for a couple of minutes.

Comment: I have fixed it. Although it seems that my command is quite long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code below works with your original code (with slight modifications).

The relevant changes are:
as suggested by [@leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis)

- You can remove `\ce`
- You can place the "`\chemfig`"s within `\schemestart` and
  `\schemestop`.
- You can use an arrow defined by the chemfig package `\arrow(.mid east--.mid
     west)`
- One suggestion made in the `\chemfig` package is to separate "plusses" and molecules using an invisible zero-length arrow (`\arrow{0}[,0]`). This causes the molecules and plusses to be treated **separately** and they end up aligning in a nicer way.
- Quoting the chemfig package: *'Therefore, one must stop the compound right after the first molecule with a \arrow{0}[,0] that will draw an invisible, zero-length arrow. In order to vertically center the whole scheme, one must also set the the anchor of the first compound as "west" ... with the second optional argument of the \schemestart command'*

  - edit: chemfig doc says you need to anchor the first compound to the "west" if you want vertical centering of the scheme. I removed the [west] argument shown below and I don't see a change in vertical alignment, so it does not seem necessary in this case.
- You can also get rid of `\mhchem` and `\mol2chemfig` (this website is awesome, by the way: https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home it has saved me countless hours)

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{+ sep left=1em, + sep right=1em, arrow offset=1em} % adjusts spacing around + symbols and the arrow
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \scalebox{0.6}{
            \schemestart[][west] % "west" may be removable here
                \chemfig{O=[:15]-[:69](-[:123,,,2]HO)=_[:357](-[:51,,,1]OH)-[:285](<[:213]O-[:141])-[:339](<[:39,,,1]OH)-[:279]-[:339,,,1]OH} \arrow{0}[,0] \+ \arrow{0}[,0]
                 \chemfig{O=[:19]-[:73]-[:1]-[:289](=[:343]O)-[:217]N(-[:145])-[:271]Br}  \arrow(.mid east--.mid west) \arrow{0}[,0]
                 \chemfig{O=[:231]-[:285](-[:339](<[:39,,,1]OH)-[:279]-[:339,,,1]OH)<[:213]O-[:141](=[:195]O)-[:69](-[:357])=[:123]O} \arrow{0}[,0] \+ \arrow{0}[,0]
                 \chemfig{O=[:18]-[:72]--[:288](=[:342]O)-[:216]{N}{H}(-[:144])} \arrow{0}[,0]  \+ 
                 \chemfig{Br-Br}
             \schemestop
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @leandriis and @pdanese!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the following is closer to the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{.47}{
\schemestart
\chemfig{O=[:15]-[:69](-[:123,,,2]HO)=_[:357](-[:51,,,1]OH)-[:285](<[:213]O-[:141])-[:339](<[:39,,,1]OH)-[:279]-[:339,,,1]OH} 
+ 
\chemfig{O=[:19]-[:73]-[:1]-[:289](=[:343]O)-[:217]N(-[:145])-[:271]Br} 
\arrow{->} 
\chemfig{O=[:15]-[:69](=[:123,,,1]O)-[:357](=[:51,,,1]O)-[:285](<[:213]O-[:141])-[:339](<[:39,,,1]OH)-[:279]-[:339,,,1]OH} 
+ 
\chemfig{O=[:18]-[:72]--[:288](=[:342]O)-[:216]\mcfbelow{N}{H}(-[:144])} 
+ 
\chemfig{Br-Br}
\schemestop
}
\end{document}
```

Wha I changed in comparison to the original:

- removed the `\ce{}` command
- placed the whole scheme between `\startscheme` and `\stopscheme`
- replaced the `mhchem`-like arrow `->` by the `chemfig` equivalent `\arrow{->}`
- replaced the code of the furan-trione derivate. For this I copied the code of the dihydroxyfuranone derivate and adjusted the bonds accordingly
- changed the factor of the `scalebox` to make sure the scheme fits into the textwidth of a standard `article` class

Comment: I am currently using Overleaf and for some reason, Overleaf tells me that file 'mol2chemfig.sty' not found. I can't produce that image.

Comment: @AnTrinh: But you aparently already used `mol2chemfig` in the example code in your question, right? At least the use of `\mcfbelow` seems to hint on that.

Comment: I go online to mol2chemfig to have it produce the code for each individual molecule. In my original code, I just hope that adding all the codes of the molecules might have produce the reaction.

Comment: @AnTrinh: Did you recieve any error message when you compile the example document in your question? If I try, I get an error message about the command `\mcfbelow` being undefined. This can be solved by adding the `mol2chemfig` package to the preamble, as I did in my answer. Aparently, the `mol2chemfig` package is not available on Overleaf.

Comment: @AnTrinh: egarding this, [Can I use my own classes and packages in ShareLaTex or Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384079/134144) might be useful.

Comment: This is my first time that I use mol2chemfig so I don't really have a mol2chemfig.sty file ready to use yet.

Comment: @AnTrinh: `mol2chemfig.sty` is a latex package that you need. You can for example find it here: chimpsky.uwaterloo.ca/m2cf_static/mol2chemfig.sty See also: https://ctan.org/pkg/mol2chemfig

Comment: "[...] contains the LaTeX macros required to compile the code generated by mol2chemfig. If you plan on using only the web interface, you still need these macros. [...]" (From the `mol2chemfig` homepage http://chimpsky.uwaterloo.ca/mol2chemfig/download)

Comment: @AnTrinh off-topic advice: tex distribution on overleaf is outdated. So, you better go offline :)