# Working my project between different computers. How?

Tags: graphics, errors, cloud

Which is the best option to keep my images?

I'm working on my thesis and sometimes I use the notebook or the computer.

At the moment, I'm keeping my LaTeX files on Google Drive. Is that the best option?

Because sometimes, when I use the computer some errors messages show to me. Like:
*Error file or Couldn't find image...*

I would like to have the liberty to work both on the notebook and the computer. What have I to do to have this liberty?

Comment: If you move to a computer that doesn't have your images, compile using `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`. It'll allow you to compile without error if the images aren't available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison: ShareLaTeX vs Overleaf (formerly WriteLaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179030/comparison-sharelatex-vs-overleaf-formerly-writelatex)

Comment: You might want to consider cloud computing https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179030/comparison-sharelatex-vs-overleaf-formerly-writelatex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online?noredirect=1&lq=1, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488049/alternatives-to-overleaf-i-e-instant-tex-compiling-without-sign-in . I have never used them, though.

Comment: I'm using git for this. Version control is good anyway.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). IMHO, I would recommend you download the Dropbox app on both computers and work in a folder in the Dropbox folder. This way you don't need to be online to work and the files will synch up next time you connect.

Comment: Clarification: where are you keeping the images?  In the same Drive folder or somewhere separate on your computer?