# Where I could find a free Latex software similar to the one on Mathstackexchange?

Tags: rendering

I find the real-time rendering of Latex on MSE really helpful.

Please post the links if this question has been already asked.

Math newbie thanks you.

Comment: It is not LaTeX. It should be `mathjax`. It is a javascript library to render a subset of latex syntax in web pages.

Comment: Can we get mathjax in a word-processing software or as a google docs addon?

Comment: Yes it's called LaTeX.

Comment: https://www.mathjax.org/ Also I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Anyway, Welcome to  [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)!

Comment: I think this is not offtopic -- if I understand the question correctly, the question asks for a LaTeX editor that has real-time rendering. This is very much on topic and would make it a duplicate of our multiple questions about real-time preview. To the OP: I recommend using an online editor like [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) or [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/), as recommended by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/best-way-to-start-using-latex-tex/371723#371723).