# Equation involving exp, sin, cos and Greek letters

Tags: math-mode

[image: Screenshot of a three line-equation]

How would I write this equation in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I hope you don't want to write the equation as it is shown in the screenshot, because it contains some typographically questionable (some might say wrong) constructs. Functions like "exp", "sin" and "cos", should be typeset in upright shape: In LaTeX that happens with `\exp`, `\sin` and `\cos`. You may also want to either decrease the size of your fractions (probably not) or increase the size of the fences/parentheses around them.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at an introduction to mathematical writing in LaTeX (and possibly a general LaTeX introduction). Equations like this should be covered there. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4420/35864,  and linked questions.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! To have the command for each symbol, you can search for it on the Internet. [This list](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols) (and many others) provides a sufficient number of symbols you need to make a mathematical document.

Using the commands to form an equation in your document is very simple and basic. You just have to read a basic LaTeX book. [LaTeX for complete novices](http://inf.ucv.ro/~mirel/courses/MIAM114/docs/LaTeX_for_complete_novices.pdf) is my recommendation.

Okay, here is your equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
We have
\[g_{\lambda\theta\psi\sigma\gamma}(x,y)=\exp\left(-\frac{x'^2+\gamma^2y'^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cos\left(2\pi\frac{x'}{\lambda}+\psi\right)\]
and
\begin{align*}
    x'&=x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)\\
    y'&=y\cos(\theta)-x\sin(\theta)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]