# Begin document with blank lines

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start off a page by adding vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33370/start-off-a-page-by-adding-vertical-space)

I'm entirely new to LaTex, but I've been googling for a while and haven't found out how to do the following:

How can I start a document with several blank lines before my first line with text? As one in MS Word would just hit enter X times at the beginning of a document.

Comment: For future reference: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-the-transition-from-microsoft-word-to-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-the-transition-from-microsoft-word-to-latex)

Comment: Thanks. I can't find any duplicate of this question (or the answer). But Boris provided an answer below, so it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do, e.g.

```
\vspace*{5\baselineskip}
```

but *why* would you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks! I expected a "why" question. Simply because an article template I am following requires three blank 12pt lines before the first sentence on the first page ...