# How to convert Word to LaTex on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I have a Word template for coursework but I prefer to write using latex. I am using latex through overleaf and was wondering how I can convert the Word template to latex so I can write on overleaf. I tried converting the PDF version of the template and uploading it on overleaf but it was converted into picture coded lines on latex.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use a third party converter (like [docx2latex](https://www.docx2latex.com/) or any other converter), an then upload the `.tex` files to Overleaf.
Till I know Overleaf does not transform .doc files to .tex automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a single converter that could convert everything correctly into a source file (especially if there are complex dianrams or formulas), but there are many sites and programs that perform similar functions:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/
- using Pandoc https://pandoc.org/
- http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/ also
- same question [What is the best way to make the transition from Microsoft Word to LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-the-transition-from-microsoft-word-to-latex)
- [Convert TeX to non-TeX and back](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16367/convert-tex-to-non-tex-and-back)